# Select Options are not working Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

While, practising over different elements using `Vue`, I got stuck at this point. When i tried to make an `option` `template` component and tried to use it in `select`, it's not working.

```js
Vue.component('todo-item', {
  
  props: ['todo'],
  template: '<option v-bind:value="todo.id">{{todo.text}}</option>'
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
 todo : [],
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!123',
    buttonText: 'Click Me',
    seen:true,
    groceryList: [
      { id: 0, text: 'Vegetables' },
      { id: 1, text: 'Cheese' },
      { id: 2, text: 'Whatever else humans are supposed to eat' }
    ]
  },
  methods:{
    buttonClick:() => {
      app.message="Button Clicked";
      app.seen=true;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
table{
  width:50%;
  border: solid 2px;
}
td{
  border: solid 1px;
  text-align:center
}
ol{
    list-style-type : none;
}
select{
  width:30%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id ="app">
  <p v-if="seen">{{message}}</p>
  <button v-on:click="buttonClick">
    {{buttonText}}
  </button>
  <br><br>
  <input v-model="message"></input>
  <br>
  <br>
<select>
   <todo-item v-for="grocery in groceryList" :todo="grocery">
</select>
  <todo-item v-for="grocery in groceryList" :todo="grocery">
    
</todo-item>

    <ul v-for="grocery in groceryList">
    <li>
      {{ grocery.text }}
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I tried to it outside the `select` tag  and also any other `html` working fine like `input`.

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Owwwvd)

Let me know in the comment section if anything you want me to do to explain my problem. Thanks

Comment: I faced the same issue because of invalid HTML. I had a `<textarea>` tag above and forgot to close it with `</textarea>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what went wrong here is not Vue or Javascript. It's how the browser handles invalid HTML.

`select` is supposed to contain only `option`.

if you do this in HTML (assuming no Javascript is used at all),

```
<select>
   <todo-item></todo-item>
   <todo-item></todo-item>
   <todo-item></todo-item>
</select>
```

the browser would remove the `todo-item` because it's invalid. https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/pZZQRz

**In your case, by the time Vue initialize, the browser has already removed the invalid HTML, which was to `todo-item`.**

You could avoid that by putting the `select` into a component as well. demo: https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/WKKYGm

```
Vue.component('basic-select', {
  template:`
<select>
  <slot></slot>
</select>
`
});
```

and use it like

```
<basic-select>
   <todo-item v-for="(grocery,i) in groceryList" :key="i" :todo="grocery">
</basic-select>
```

This way, Vue function would be applied without browser messing with it.

This kind of issue would only happen when you use Vue directly in browser without using build tools and vue-loader. In a typical vue-cli generated project, all html template is handle inside Vue single file component and all html would be compiled by Vue before browser use it

Comment: Thanks, got the point here. I was for a time thought of it but just wanted to confirm if i am not doing anything wrong with vue syntax which is making me trouble doing this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `select` tag you need to use `option` tags inside of it.

In the document of vue:

```
<select v-model="selected">
  <!-- inline object literal -->
  <option v-bind:value="{ number: 123 }">123</option>
</select>
```

In your example you can use it like:

```
<select v-model="selectedGrocery">
  <option v-bind:value="grocery.id" v-for="grocery in groceryList">
      {{grocery.text}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: I knew this specific way to achieve this but i want it to get used as component and if it not possible that means i cannot import it as a component ? If yes than select Options cannot be used in component module.

Comment: @satyampathak select and option are OS based elements. So you can not change their structure you can just change their css. If you want to use select option as a component you need to create your own component without using them. There is a simple example for autocompleter https://codepen.io/robrogers3/full/WKjGZE

Answer (score -1):

In the select tag, do the v-bind BEFORE v-for.
so DO this:

```
<select v-model="selectedGrocery">
  <option v-bind:value="grocery.id" v-for="grocery in groceryList">
      {{grocery.text}}
  </option>
```

NOT this:

```
<select v-model="selectedGrocery">
  <option  v-for="grocery in groceryList" v-bind:value="grocery.id">
      {{grocery.text}}
  </option>
</select>
```